# is it possible to create a 100% leak free ipad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks

I am developing an iPad app and found some memory leaks using Instruments and Analyzer. I tried to release some objects which resulted in the crashing of my app.. Are memory leaks allowed in an app? If so, until what extent they are allowed? Is there a way to completely remove the memory leaks with out the app getting crashed??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is possible to make sure that the *code which you write* is leak free. This is not to say that Apple frameworks and internal libraries won't leak at all.

If you call `alloc`, `new` or `copy` make sure to call a corresponding `release` or `autorelease`. Apps that leak a lot are bound to crash often. Apps that crash often are likely to be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: hi moshe.... thanku for ur intrest in answering my question.... I really dont know why u gave me a negative voting.... and i think that is absolutely unnecessary in this context.... anyway... thanku for ur answer again...

Comment: I did not down vote. It must have been someone else. I actually voted up. Feel free to select my answer if yu feel that it is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Please read [this](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/). We can create an application with 100% leak free. Enable NSZombieEnabled to check why the crash occurs.

Comment: +1 for that link. Some of the info seems to be old but still relevant. Great Read!

Comment: Hi king... thanku for ur answer... I have seen this document earlier through google and found it really helpful. But i have no idea about NSZombieEnabled.. an u please tell me a bit more on that..... thanku

Comment: check this link http://www.quickiphonetips.com/2010/12/how-to-track-exec_bad_access-nszombieenabled

Comment: Yes, we can, but only if all the frameworks and libraries we use are also leak free. Generally, you are only responsible for your own code and for your choice of 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to remove as many leaks as you can.

But if there are a few remaining in your application that *you can't* remove, Apple will still accept your application - as long it doesn't crash frequently.

Just make sure when you `alloc` something - it's released with `release` or `autorelease`.

That's the best way of making sure leaks don't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Leaks are much, much easier to not have in the first place than to try plugging later when the app has memory issues.  Fortunately in the iOS/Cocoa world the memory management rules are clear and simple.  However as others have said there could be leaks in code you didn't write :(